Sort by entry title not post date in Sprig board
I am building a sortable 'board' of projects using Sprig: https://staging24.moxonarchitects.com/projects/projectBoard#
the 'country' column is playing up though — this column is output using:

{% for projectCountry in entry.projectCountries.all() %}
                        
        {{ projectCountry }}
                        
{% endfor %}

and the sort is set at the head of the column here
<a sprig s-val:order-by="projectCountries" s-val:sort-by="{{ orderBy == 'projectCountries' and sortBy == 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc' }}" href="#" class="hover:underline">Country</a>


BUT — the column orders by post date of the 'projectCountry' NOT by the title of the country?!
my basic query is
{% set entryQuery = craft.entries({
    search: search,
    orderBy: orderBy ~ ' ' ~ sortBy,
    section: 'projects',
    relatedTo: projectsCategories,
}) %}

Any help much appreciated :)
